# AttributeError in Python(Quiz Game, importing dictionary)

Tags: python, attributeerror

Im making a python quiz game and I have some problem.
The questions and answers is imported from a dictionary in another python file. But I run into this error:

> return correct.strip().lower() == answer.strip().lower()
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

I think I understand that the problem is that strip and lower only can be applied to strings, but I dont know where to put it elsewhere?

```
from questions import quiz

print("------ Welcome to Python quiz ------")


def compare_answer(correct: str, answer: str) -> bool:
    return correct.strip().lower() == answer.strip().lower()


score = 0
for question in quiz:
    print(quiz[question]['question'])
    user_answer = input("> ")
    correct_answer = quiz[question]["answer"]
    if compare_answer(correct_answer, user_answer):
        score += 1
        print(f"Right!")
    else:
        print(f"Wrong, the right answer is: {correct_answer}")
print(f"You got {score} of 3 possible right!")
```

This is one of the questions from the dictionary

```
quiz = {
    1: {
        "question": "Question 1. Which function is used to print out things?"
                    " \n 1. input \n 2. print \n 3. len",
        "answer": [{"answer": "2",
                    "correct": True},
                   {"answer": "print",
                    "correct": True}]

       
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

`quiz[question]["answer"]`, a.k.a `correct_answer` or `correct` inside the function is a *list* (of dictionaries), not a *string*. The error means exactly what it says: You can't call `.strip()` on a list. You want to check if *any* of the answers in `correct` is equal to `answer`

Each element of `correct` is a dictionary of the form

```
{"answer": "2",
"correct": True}
```

You need to check if *any* of these dictionaries has an `"answer"` key that is equal to the user's answer, and also has a `True` value in the `"correct"` key

```
def compare_answer(correct: list, answer: str) -> bool:
    return any(ca["correct"] and ca["answer"].strip().lower() == answer for ca in correct)
```

Alternatively, if you *must* use take two strings in the`compare_answer` function, you can modify the way it's called:

```
if any(ca["correct"] and compare_answer(ca["answer"], user_answer) for ca in correct_answer):
    score += 1
    print(f"Right!")
```

Comment: I dont get it to work. The first code you linked, ca isnt used anywhere and I dont know what to do with it. correct: list isnt used either and I dont know what to with it. The best result I have got is that I can write both 2 and print as a answer and its right, but it prints out all the list like this: {"answer": "2", "correct": True} {"answer": "print", "correct": True}. Is there an easier way to do this? So the user can both write 2 and print and get right?

Comment: I think you're missing a `for ca in correct` in the first code

Comment: @Tomerikoo that fixed one thing. But now I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kevin\PycharmProjects\quiz\python_quiz.py", line 16, in <module>
    if compare_answer(correct_answer, user_answer):
  File "C:\Users\kevin\PycharmProjects\quiz\python_quiz.py", line 8, in compare_answer
    return any(ca["correct"] and ca["answer"].strip().lower() == answer)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Comment: @KevinR That's what I was saying, it misses the loop. Should be: `return any(ca["correct"] and ca["answer"].strip().lower() == answer for ca in correct)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo ooh, that explains it. I was putting it over, not in the line. Thanks, now that work. The only problem left is that the whole list of answers is printed when the user is taking the wrong answer. "Wrong, the right answer is: [{'answer': '2', 'correct': True}, {'answer': 'print', 'correct': True}]" is printed. Do I need to change a name of a key or make a new function to make it work?